# For loop only printing last iteration

Tags: javascript, html

My for loop is only printing the last iteration.

moving `document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = str;` out and in for loop.

HTML (Placed after javascript code)

```
<p id="alert" style="color: white"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.directory.chromeosdevices.list({
        "customerId": "my_customer"
    }).then(function(response1) {
        // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
        var str = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var obj = response1.result
            var obj2 = obj.chromeosdevices[i];
            var str = JSON.stringify(obj2.model);
            str += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = str;           
    },
    function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}
```

Outputs:

```
"Acer Chromebook 11 (C740)"The number is 4
```

Outputs wanted

```
"Acer Chromebook 11 (C740)"The number is 0
"Acer Chromebook 11 (C740)"The number is 1
"Acer Chromebook 11 (C740)"The number is 2
"Acer Chromebook 11 (C740)"The number is 3
"Acer Chromebook 11 (C740)"The number is 4
```

Comment: With `document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = str` you're overwriting whatever previously existed in the element, use `+=` instead

Comment: Am I not using it in this line? str += "The number is " + i + "<br>";   , do I delete document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = str and replace it with document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML += str ?

Comment: The `str` is reassigned inside the loop with `var str = JSON.stringify(obj2.model);`, which doesn't preserve whatever `str` was previously assigned as. Code is generally easier to read and write when there isn't unnecessary reassignment involved

Comment: Isn't that what I want? I want the output to be different each time i print obj.chromeosdevices[i] while i is 0 - 4. Im new to javascript so I may be doing this the wrong/long way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the assignment operator (`=`) *replaces* any value previously stored in a variable. Therefore, as you go through the loop and hit the `var str = JSON.stringify(obj2.model)` line, any previous value in `str` is replaced. Therefore, once you're out of the loop, only the last assignment is made. Furthermore, using `var` the way you're doing is incorrect. `var` declares a variable in the scope of a function. The `var str = ''` declaration before the loop defines the variable, so the `var str` *inside* the loop is invalid, though the engine is being forgiving and just assigning over the top of the old value. Nowadays, you should rarely ever use `var` when less confusing alternatives like `let` and `const` are available.

As @CertainPerformance stated, doing a bunch of assignment statements makes code harder to follow, since you have to mentally go through the history of what's in a variable. Something like this would be a cleaner bit of code because it doesn't reassign a bunch of times. Note I'm also using more modern JS (not IE compatible), so disregard that change if you cannot use async/await:

```
async function execute() {
    try {
      const { result } = await gapi.client.directory.chromeosdevices.list({
        "customerId": "my_customer"
      });

      const alertDiv = document.getElementById("alert");
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const { model } = result.chromeosdevices[i];
        const line = `Device ${i} has model ${JSON.stringify(model)}`;
        alertDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(line)); // Safely encode text
        alertDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      }
    } catch (err) { 
      console.error("Execute error", err); 
    }
}
```

Comment: im getting a Incaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return on the const { result } line